# getting Error : Couldnt find or load main class while starting WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2

I am very new to WSO2 and trying to use it. 
I downloaded wso2esb-4.7.0 and as given in `Install.txt`. 
I tried running `wso2server.bat start`

But getting Error :

```
Couldn't find or load main class
```

Here is the command that i am executing on my cmd:

```
D:\Milton\wso2esb-4.7.0\bin>wso2server.bat start
```

Path Variables:

- `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25`
- `CARBON_HOME` environment variable is set to
  `D:\wso2as-5.2.1\`

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

If your java environment working properly, please go to ..\wso2esb-4.7.0\bin  and run wso2server.bat  without parameter. ( also you have set CARBON_HOME  as wso2as  and not esb ,just remove it startup script will pick it automatically)

..\wso2esb-4.7.0\bin> wso2server.bat

Also if you getting this error still, try unpacking esb to new location and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have manually configured the CARBON_HOME environment variable in your Windows environment. It's been set to D:\wso2as-5.2.1. But you are starting an ESB instance which is located at another folder.

WSO2 products are capable of automatically determining the value for the CARBON_HOME variable. So, remove the environment variable you have manually configured, and start the wso2 server.